# Kleene plus in Thompson's construction

Tags: automata, finite-automata, regular-expressions

**Is there a direct way to represent Kleene plus(+) using  Thompson's construction algorithm?**

When I studied Thompson's construction I learned how to transform concatenation, union and kleene star of regular expresions directly into a NFA.

In wikipedia(and other websites) I found the same thing I learned in college(nothing about Kleene plus):[Thompson's construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thompson%27s_construction)

In a non-direct method we can always transform $R^+$ in $RR^*$ and then use Thompson construction.

There is a [website](http://hackingoff.com/compilers/regular-expression-to-nfa-dfa) that transform regular expressions into NFA. They claim to use Thompson-McNaughton-Yamada algorithm. Here they transform $a^+$ into:

[image]

Is this some kind of extension of Thompson's construction algorithm?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's technically an "extension" in the sense that [Ken Thompson's original paper (ACM DL subscription required)](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?doid=363347.363387) doesn't mention it. This is presumably because his regular expression compiler didn't support "+" syntax in 1968.

However, pretty much every textbook presentation of Thompson's algorithm (e.g. see [Bruce Watson's 1995 review paper on FA construction](http://alexandria.tue.nl/extra1/wskrap/publichtml/9313452.pdf)) mentions it. It's likely that no one person "extended" the method in Thompson's paper, or the "extension" was done by Thompson when he decided to support "+".